# flex dropdown: how do I know if the list expands above or below?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, drop-down-menu

So in flex when you click on a drop down the list that pops out can either come below the drop down tab or above the tab. I'm guessing because if there isn't enough room below the screen it pops the list above the tab. How would I know if it expands above or below? As a side question, is there a way to control where the list pops up, say only to expand below the tab?

Comment: This [link][1] may be helpful to you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266123/flex-is-there-a-way-to-specify-what-direction-a-combobox-will-open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can either do like what gdcool mentioned from the link and build the whole menu for yourself. But I found an even easier solution and compared the mouseY properties as such:

var pointy:Number = this.contentMouseY;

var pointyDropList:Number = this.dropDown.mouseY;

So simply put the pointy variable determines the mouse Y position relative to the tab ("this" is the drop down object) and the pointyDropList variable determines the mouse Y position relative to the drop down list. If the drop down list expands below then pointyDropList variable will always be less than the pointy. Otherwise if the drop down list expands above the pointyDropList will always be greater than the pointy variable. So basically:

```
if(pointyDropList > pointy)
{
    //the drop down is above the tab
}
else
{
   //the drop down is below the tab
}
```